# Is it possible to have graphic packs for Android?

Tags: android, graphics, android-resources

So I have an app that has an interface that is completely customize-able except for graphics. Until recently I was using the built in resource capabilities of Android and enjoying the ease of doing so (R.drawable.filename was nice). The downside to using this interface however is that it requires for all of the graphics to be part of the APK itself.

What I want to be able to do is give an interface to the users for downloading graphic packs that they can then swap out and use a new one with out forcing a 300MB APK on them that contains all of them. Is there some kind of standard interface that I am simply missing to make this work that is used in things like In-App purchases? Or is my only choice to roll out a proprietary graphic pack data file and then an interface for utilizing it?

Let me know!

Thanks.

Comment: Interesting question.  For some types of elements you can clearly create them yourself from file data.  For others though (such as status bar notification icons) the APIs seem to require a resource identifier - ie, a bare number - which seems hard to reconcile with an alternative image source.

Comment: Yeah I have come to the understanding that there are some APIs I will not be able to utilize loading my graphics (and maybe sound effects, I keep getting more ambitious with every hill I climb). But overall the trade off is not to bad, I can keep some general graphics in the R file but let the major interface graphics be swapped out.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Yes, the APIs require an integer resource identifier, but this should not be hard to reconcile because all resources automatically translate into integers...you just need to pass in r.id.some_resource_name

Comment: @CoderOfTheNight - this question concerns adding new graphic elements *at runtime*, while the mechanism you are speaking of operates at *build time*.  It is not clear how one could add additional resources which *system library code* would be able to find by number at runtime.